# System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression parsing expressions with enum parameters

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I am trying to parse a LambdaExpression Tree using DynamicExpression.ParseLambda but I cannot get it to correctly parse when using string.Equals with the StringComparison enum.

I have tried:

a) using StringComparison but I get the error 'Unknown identifier 'StringComparison''.

b) using the full namespace of System.StringComparison but I get the error 'Unknown identifier 'System''.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void CanParseStringEqualsWithEnum()
    {
        var input = @"p0.Equals(""Testing"", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)";

        var p0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p0");

        System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p0 }, typeof(bool), input);
    }
```

Removing the StringComparison works.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CanParseStringEqualsWithEnum()
{
    var input = @"p0.Equals(""Testing"")";

    var p0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p0");

    System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p0 }, typeof(bool), input);
}
```

I could perform .ToUpper() on both strings and compare that way, but I know this doesn't cover all scenarios and it's better to use StringComparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution (which does not involve code-changes) is using the value **3** for the enumeration.

When using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core), the following code works:

```cs
var input = @"p0.Equals(""Testing"", 3)";
var p0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p0");
var expression = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { p0 }, typeof(bool), input);
Delegate del = expression.Compile();
var result = del.DynamicInvoke("testing") as bool?;
```

**UPDATE**

I've changed the code for [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) (version 1.0.16). Now it's also possible to use:

```cs
var input = @"p0.Equals(""Testing"", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)";
// ...
```

Comment: Good to find out there is a github project that's actively getting updated. Thank you for the quick change, now using this project instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31654108) and went with patching the sources for the System.Linq.Dynamic library.
Downloaded the package sources from GitHub and added System.StringComparison to the "predefinedTypes" array of Types within System.ExpressionParser.

**UPDATE**: See Stef's answer for a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56472200/785965